# converting component from Joomla 2.5 to 3.x

Tags: joomla-api, administrator, custom-component

I'm trying to convert a component from Joomla 2.5 to 3.x.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The admin component controller has:

```
class PatientinvoicesModelPatientinvoices extends JModelLegacy {
```

then I have the view controller

```
class PatientinvoicesControllerPatientinvoices extends JControllerAdmin
```

and the model

```
class PatientinvoicesModelPatientinvoices extends JModelLegacy {
```

finally I have the view.html which has

```
class PatientinvoicesViewPatientinvoices extends JView
```

I thought that changing to this would allow it to work. I guess I'm missing something. Can someone suggest how I can debug it to figure out what the issue is? (I'd be happy to add more code for any of it if it would help)

thanks

edit

I've now also changed

```
class PatientinvoicesViewPatientinvoices extends JViewLegacy
```

instead of just JView  (didn't fix it though :(

Comment: please provide more information as if you were able to install the component to J3.x, as there are also changes in the main XML file. If you have already installed the component to J3.x, what error do you get. These issues will help us understand your issue better

Answer (score 0):

I spent my weekend working this out so hopefully it'll help someone else when they look.  Once you know what to look for and what to change it's quite mechanistic.  There are really only a few things that need changed.  But it's hard to find it all set out in one place and easy to keep trying different combinations.  If you follow these rules then it should work without too much extra debugging.

For me the key was only changing the extension of the class even although it was tempting to adjust lots of the code!

**Upgrading from version 2.5 to 3.x**

I’m assuming the component is already installed and that it worked on 2.5.  I was upgrading a site to 3.8 so I upgraded the site and then came back to upgrade the component (this might not work in your case especially if a 2.5 component has plugins and aren't compatible with 3.x - in that case I suggest delete the plugins and sort it out once the upgrade to Joomla is complete).

Go to the root of the component and find the **componentname.php** file.

There will be a line which has JController  this needs changed to **JControllerLegacy**

**$controller   = JControllerLegacy::getInstance(‘RelevantView’);**

Next go the the **controller.php** (also in the root)  change the class to be extended  **JControllerLegacy**

**class ComponentNameController extends JControllerLegacy {**

If you have **sub controllers** ( in a controllers folder)  you need to make sure that the extension of the class is:

For **list view JControllerAdmin**
For **single view  JControllerForm**

Next go to the **models** folder.  For each model:

For **list view  JModelList**
For **single view  JModelAdmin**

Finally go to the **views** and the **view.html** files.

All of these should use **JViewLegacy**

**class ComponentNameViewLetter extends JViewLegacy {**

There are some other things like JUtilty and JRequest that have been deprecated that might throw errors you should sort them on a case by case basis.   See here:

https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2